# How to limit the number of process that a user can create?

Tags: process, fork

I think I have a program that creates countless forks of itself (not intentionally, I hope).

I like to test this but I can't kill the machine, so how could I limit the number of process to execute this in a sage way?

Comment: Did you forget to finish your title?

Answer (score 3):

`ulimit` is used to temporarily establish limits to the current shell and its sons.

You can limit the number of process with `ulimit -u $desired_number`

More info in `man ulimit` and `ulimit -a`

Answer (score 2):

limit.conf file

e.g. User1 to 20

```
user1 hard nproc 20
```

e.g. group1 to 50

```
@group1 hard nproc 50
```

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/how-to-set-limits-on-users.html#ixzz2vJifNgrT